# logback \ log4j - a rotating log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I'm looking for a log file, size based, that will only log the last 10MB or so,
without rolling older data to archived files.
meaning - after 10MB all older data will be deleted, and new entries will be added a row-for-row.

found some policies, but none seem to keep the original file name.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use the following two log4j properties:

```
log4j.appender.loggerId.MaxFileSize=10MB  
log4j.appender.loggerId.MaxBackupIndex=1
```

When your file has reached 10Mb log4j will rotate id but keeping at most 1 file as backup.

Comment: won't help - every 10MB it truncates the entire file and starts over - i need to delete just the oldest entries.